# Regex of 7 characters with up to 2 dashes

Tags: regex

I couldn't create a search query to find in previous answers, so I'll post.
How do I create a string of exactly 7 characters where 0-2 of them can be dash (in any place), 5-7 of them \w character? All I thought of is

```
^(\w?){5}([\w-]?){2}(\w?){5}$
```

but I know through regex101 it can sum up to 12 chars (

Comment: Can the dashes be adjacent, leading or trailing?

Comment: They can be on any of 7 places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```regex
(?=^(?:\w*-?\w*){2}$)^.{7}$
```

- `(?=` - start lookahead

  - `^(?:\w*-?\w*){2}$` - from start to finish ensure we have all `\w` characters and allow for a maximum of 2 dashes anywhere in the string
- `)` - end lookahead
- `^.{7}$` - capture 7 chars

https://regex101.com/r/L7IReu/1/

Comment: I know the OP used `\w` but I think `[^-]` which would be any non-dash character would be more approriate.

Comment: But how O_O You're a magician! 
Thank you - go to read the manual and decipher 

Comment: Thank you, but [^-] could mean / or * or . and I needed specifically hyphens

Comment: @trinalbadger587 In addition to thinking, verify. Try your suggestion at the regex101 link and you'll see that the result is not what OP described in their question.

Comment: @MikeWhitefox, no I mean non-dash characters. `\w` eg. `123456&` is not valid but it is 7 characters with up to 2 dashes. see https://regex101.com/r/FZopXM/1

Comment: @trinalbadger587 `123456&` is supposed to be invalid per their question.

Comment: @trinalbadger587 I meant but [^-] could mean / or * or . and I needed specifically \w. But I couldn't edit the message

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be to assert 7 characters and optionally match 1 or 2 hyphens between word characters.

```
^(?=[\w-]{7}$)\w*(?:-\w*){0,2}$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=[\w-]{7}$)` Assert 7 word chars or `-` in the whole string
- `\w*` Match optional word chars
- `(?:-\w*){0,2}` Repeat 0-2 times matching `-` and optional word chars
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ybL0Dd/1)

Comment: I am impressed with how many fewer steps this solution takes compared to my answer =)

Comment: I wonder, btw, why that happens (no, I don't understand their debugger =) ). And although its 85 steps against 523, its still 0.7 ms against 0.8 . So, ( each | some ) of operations seems to cost more time.

Comment: I know it's not correct to measure bulk, but each word is different number of operations / CPU time.

Comment: @MikeWhitefox The difference in steps in on regex101 is due to the backtracking when the lookahead does not find a match. I think if you want to measure the performance, you should take a real dataset and then measure the performance of the code. Some regex engines can have optimization features before running the pattern.